# Updating entities on csv import (dynamics crm 2011 online)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

**While importing csv data in dynamics 2011 online, is there any option of updating existing entities instead of creating new ones ?**

For example, I have certain custom fields on the Lead Entity (each lead is identified uniquely by email).
At some point, an attribute of a lead changes.

Can this new value be imported via csv, also maintaining the other existing lead attributes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is get Dynamics to provide you with an xml file of your data which you can edit and re-import with changes.

- Open advanced find and locate the record you want to change some
  values of
- Add the appropiate columns you want to edit
- Click "Export" in the ribbon
- Check the box "Make this data available for re-importing..." and
  click Export

Now you are free to edit your records(s) in an xml file (Excel works nicely) which you can update and then import as standard via Data Management > Imports > Import Data.

Comment: In my case, the csv data file is generated by a third party application, so editing the exported xml is not a solution in my case. Is there an alternative for this, that will work by just providing one or more new values for the lead + existing email identifier ?

Comment: @DanielHursan There is no alternative that I'm aware of... I had a look online and it seems others were able to do what you require in CRM 4.0, see [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/c8819e57-ccfc-4167-ad62-947d6d15651c). But from what I can see, the only way in manipulate data in CRM 2011 is through export and re-import of the generated xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Spencerooni's answer is correct so far as native support for what you're asking (edit: and as far as IE9 can take you). To handle external CSVs via the CRM client, though, you will have to do the reading of the CSV and the updating yourself. I can think of one way to do this:

1. Create a section in your site map devoted specifically to CSV imports from this third party source, or if you're feeling adventurous, devoted to all generic CSV imports.
2. Create a web resource where you prompt the user to select a file on the client machine. To get started on this, you can reference the SO answer "[The future is here!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7011100/684271)".
3. Read the selected file(s) via the HTML5 `File` object and process the updates to your `Lead`s via JScript CRM calls. To process the updates via C#/VB.NET, you can reference the SO question "[Call C# Code from Ribbon JScript CRM Online 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091565/call-c-sharp-code-from-ribbon-jscript-crm-online-2011)" and its accepted answer.
4. Point the sitemap to reference your web resource, and that should just about do it.

Edit: Forgot to add that to handle any of this, you'll need to upgrade to the IE10 Preview(!). Or wait until CRM 2011 gets [multi-browser support](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crmbusiness/archive/2011/09/06/microsoft-dynamics-crm-will-offer-cross-browser-support-chrome-firefox-and-safari-in-future-updates.aspx). Whichever comes first.

- [HTML5: File API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673546.aspx#File_API)
- [CRM 2011 running in IE 10 on Windows 8!!](https://twitter.com/#!/miketsnyder/status/113867791030956033)

Comment: Multi-browser support coming Q2 2012. http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2012/feb12/02-06CRMMobilePR.mspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this article, which explains how to use CRM's OrganizationService from Powershell to do the updating for you based on a .CSV file (by the looks of it, it should apply to CRM2011 as well):

[MS CRM 2015: Bulk update data using Powershell](http://blogs.infosupport.com/ms-crm-2015-bulk-update-data-using-powershell/)