# Trigger a plugin when entity opens in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can we trigger a plugin when we click on the account entity link from side navigation, like Workplace > Account.
Normally we can create Create or Update plugin, but I need such plugin which will fire when a entity is open. which Message we have to write when we register the plugin through plugin registration tool if we can do the above?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it myself but I believe there is a plugin message 'Retrieve'.

There is a simple-enough-to-follow blog post on it [here](http://davecorun.com/blog/2012/01/05/crm-2011retrieve-plugin/).

Comment: +1, but I can see this becoming a real resource hog over time (as the blogger mentions). The `RetrieveMultiple` message might also be applicable.

Comment: FWIW agree with @PeterMajeed - as always, developer beware :)

Comment: Keep also in mind, that you are not able to detect *who* retrieves a record (form, web service, ...)

Answer (score 0):

A quick *supported* kludge I can think of is to use a [`CustomRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309433.aspx) on a bogus button in the `HomepageGrid` ribbon to trigger the creation of a custom entity that in turn activates a Create plugin. See the below links for more detail.

- [Define Ribbon Enable Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334682.aspx)
- [Call C# Code from Ribbon JScript CRM
  Online 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5093860/684271)