# Copy PhoneCall `to` and `from` fields to the new PhoneCall

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm making a button on PhoneCall ribbon that creates *follow up call*. I've tried to do this with javascript, with [XrmServiceToolkit](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/). Looks like I can't do it at all with SOAP end point and doing it with REST is some what tricky.

How do I copy `to` and `from` fields to a new activity?

**Update** Originally I tried using XrmServiceToolkit javascript library, but switched to C# for copying fields, following Peter's answer.

Still, no result. I do it this way:

```
EntityCollection toCollection = new EntityCollection();
foreach (var activityParty in ((EntityCollection)previousActivity["to"]).Entities)
{
    Entity newActivityParty = new Entity(ActivityParty.EntityLogicalName);
    newActivityParty["activityid"] = new EntityReference(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId);
    newActivityParty["partyid"] = activityParty["partyid"];
    newActivityParty["participationtypemask"] = new OptionSetValue(2);//activityParty["participationtypemask"];
    //service.Create(newActivityParty);

    toCollection.Entities.Add(newActivityParty);
}
entity["to"] = toCollection;
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Would you be open to using .NET instead of javascript?

Comment: Yes, if it won't require external installer, like web-service would.

Comment: See my answer below (edited today) for a good way to handle this server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing it with JavaScript, after all:

```js
function main() {
    var newActivity = new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity('phonecall');

    newActivity.attributes['phonecall'] = {
        id : Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(),
        logicalName : 'phonecall',
        type : 'EntityReference'
    }

    newActivity.attributes['to'] = {
        type: 'EntityCollection',
        value: lookupToEntityReferenceCollection('to')
    }

    var newId = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(newActivity);
}

function lookupToEntityReferenceCollection(lookupName) {
    var result = [],
        lookupValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupName).getValue();

    if (lookupValue === null) {return result;}

    var arrayLength = lookupValue.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength;i++) {
        result.push({
            id: lookupValue[i].id, 
            logicalName: lookupValue[i].typename,
            type: 'EntityReference'
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding it troublesome with JavaScript and you want a more front-end way of doing things, you could have a solution where you click your ribbon button which opens a new phone call form with the details you require pre-populated. You construct the URL with the parameters you require from your current form and this will set the values on your new form (your follow up phone call). Take a look at [MSDN - Setting field values using paramaters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx).

You should be able to copy your `to` and `from` fields to the new form this way.

Note that this is an alternative. If you're wanting to **completely** automate the creation of the follow up phone call with JavaScript then I'd recommend using the REST endpoint and posting some code if you have difficulties.

Comment: Passing parameters to a form will not do, because: 
>You cannot set the values for partylist or regarding lookups.
So, I'll update question with REST code.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** On thinking this over, the most logically correct approach is as follows:

1. Create a self-referential lookup field/relationship in the `PhoneCall` entity (the target of which is `PhoneCall`), called something like `new_OriginatingCall`. This will provide you your trail of follow up phone calls.
2. Create a `Create`, pre-operation/validation plug-in on the `PhoneCall` entity that checks for the existence of a value in the `new_OriginatingCall` field. If it exists, populate the `to` and `from` fields from the originating `PhoneCall`.
3. In the javascript attached to your button, create a new `PhoneCall` with the `new_OriginatingCall` populated.

This way, no matter how a follow-up call is generated, the `to` and `from` fields are always populated correctly server-side.

Edit: See below for a sample of how to retrieve and set `PartyList`s via Linq.

```cs
// newPc is the Target entity of the plugin.
var pc = xsc.PhoneCallSet
    .Single(x => x.ActivityId == newPc.new_OriginatingCall.Id);
// pc is now a copy of the original phone call.

// Have to make new activity party lists because the activity parties attached to
// the original phone call activity have the activity id set to the original
// phone call.
// Trying to attach them unchanged to the new phone call (which would have a new 
// activity id) results in a FaultException.
var to = pc.To.Select(x => new ActivityParty { PartyId = x.PartyId });
var from = pc.From.Select(x => new ActivityParty { PartyId = x.PartyId });

// Prep the new phone call.
PhoneCall pcNew = new PhoneCall
{
    To = to,
    From = from,
    Subject = pc.Subject,
    ActualDurationMinutes = pc.ActualDurationMinutes,
    DirectionCode = pc.DirectionCode,
    PhoneNumber = pc.PhoneNumber
};

// Create the new phone call.
service.Create(pcNew);
```

<s>If you can more easily assemble `PartyList`s in .NET than in javascript, I strongly recommend using one of the two best answers suggested in the great question [Call C# Code from Ribbon JScript CRM Online 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5091565/684271) (i.e. trigger your code via the creation of a "plugin" custom entity or include a field in the `PhoneCall` entity that is set via javascript, and on update, triggers a plugin that examines the state of that field and reacts accordingly).</s>

I've used both approaches often, as it's often complicated to achieve similar results in the CRM with javascript.

Comment: That's clever! I'll give it a try and report the result.

Comment: How do I copy this fields in C#? Tried obvious ways with no result :(

Comment: I tried to make late-bound version out of your sample, but ended up switching back to js. Target entity can not be modified with LINQ on pre-Create, as far as I know :(

Comment: @skfd: Two things: 1) Why use late-bound entities? If you need a hand getting started developing using early-bound classes, that would probably make things easier. 2) Linq is a query language, not (really) a way to set values for entities. So the values are queried via Linq, but the Target entity can be updated whether you use Linq to get your values or not. In any event, glad you got it working via  javascript, which can always be a challenge (though presumably you'd want to get it working server side eventually).

Comment: By "modified with LINQ" I meant "modified as an early-bound class".
I'd love to use early-bound, but TargetEntity comes as an `Entity`, not an early-bound class. I tried doing: `entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]; entity["to"] = pc.To.Select(x => new ActivityParty { PartyId = x.PartyId });`, but it threw type mismatch -- one is IEnumerable, other is EntityCollection. I tried couple of things to fix it, but they did not work.

Comment: You can cast the `Target` `Entity` object as a CRM object by using something like this: `var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]; PhoneCall phoneCall = entity.ToEntity<PhoneCall>();`. You can then assign values to that new CRM object the same way you would to `Target`.

Comment: Wow, casting `Target` to `Entity` this way works like a charm! Thank you, Peter.