# Creating a parent and child entity in one transaction, AddRelatedObject throws an exception

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow

I've created an assembly to use within a workflow in Dynamics 365 v9.

I have a Parent entity with a 1:N parental relationship to my Child entity.
I want to create the Parent and Child in the same transaction so that if anything fails the whole thing is rolled back.

The documentation says this is done with the [AddRelatedObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg307129(v%3Dcrm.8)) method.

```
var parent = new Parent()
{
    Name = "PARENT"
};

var child = new Child()
{
    Name = "CHILD"
};

crmContext.AddObject(parent);
crmContext.AddRelatedObject(parent, new Relationship("my_relationship"), child);
crmContext.SaveChanges();
```

The classes for Parent and Child were created with the Early Bound Generator plugin for XrmToolbox and have not been altered.

When I call `SaveChanges` I get the exception:

> Message: An error occured while processing this request.
>   Inner Message: Cannot find record to be updated

I don't know why this is occurring. The same code works in CRM 2011.
If I remove the `AddRelatedObject` line the parent is created just fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me turned out to be a separate workflow connected to the child entity that tries to update the parent entity. It was upset because it assumed there was a parent when there was not.

I put a `Check Condition` at the start of the workflow to terminate it if there's no parent record which has now solved the error.

I didn't realise that errors caused in other plugins/workflows would bubble up to mine.

For anyone else getting this error I'd check two things:

- Plugins registered against either parent or child entities
- Workflows associated to either parent or child entities

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028749/crm-2011-sdk-transaction), you might want to give this a shot:

```
EntityA primaryEntity = new EntityA() { //initialise me... };
EntityB secondaryEntity = new EntityB() { //initialise me... };

context.AddObject(primaryEntity);
context.AddObject(secondaryEntity);

// This is the key part: explicitly link the two entities
context.AddLink(primaryEntity, 
    new Relationship("relationship_name_here"), secondaryEntity);

// commit changes to CRM
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The `AddRelatedObject` method basically calls those two methods together so this code is equivalent to mine and will throw the exception.